# NavigationLink on macOS not opening in the same View

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm currently building a macOS App with `SwiftUI` (no Catalyst) that is supposed to have a Sidebar and a single View to the right of it.

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ...
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())

    HomeView()
}
```

My Home View has a `NavigationLink` inside of it, pointing to another `DetailView`.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("DetailView", destination: Text("This is the DV"))
    }
}
```

This NavigationLink always appears as disabled and only works when I add another Column to the `NavigationView`. I don't want another Column, but rather the `NavigationLink` *replacing* the `HomeView` with the `DetailView`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I believe there is a bug preventing this to work properly. When I’m trying to do that the new window was always opening in a small overlay. I submitted a bug report  to apple already during early betas end of June but didn’t get any feedback. I would recommend you to submit a feedback to apple as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently SwiftUI 2 does not support pushing views on to the Navigation Stack on macOS yet. However, I found this package that helps to resolve the issue:

[github.com/lbrndnr/StackNavigationView](https://github.com/lbrndnr/StackNavigationView)

Answer (score 0):

NavigationLinks always open a detail view from the current "column" of the navigation view, so if your navigation link is rendered as a child view of HomeView then it will try to open as a detail view of HomeView (the missing third column). If you want a view to replace the HomeView the intended way then the user should select something from the List. If you're trying to programmatically select a NavigationLink that already exists in your list then you should do so by changing state within the HomeView of a variable that is bound to the selected item of the list or the selection of the NavigationLink within the list. Here's a complete working example that does both within the ContentView.swift of a new MacOS SwiftUI Xcode project

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var selectedItem: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello") {
            selectedItem = "Thing2"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: String?
    private let items = ["Thing1", "Thing2"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedItem) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text(item),
                        tag: item,
                        selection: $selectedItem
                    ) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            HomeView(selectedItem: $selectedItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the application displaying the HomeView

[image: HomeView]

And here is the application displaying the selected thing after pressing the button

[image: Selected Thing]

If you don't want to show anything selected in the list after navigating the view, but still want to use a navigation link to maintain the integrity of the navigation within the NavigationView then you could technically put a hidden navigation link in the list

```
NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedItem) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text(item),
                        tag: item,
                        selection: $selectedItem
                    ) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Sneaky"),
                    tag: "Sneaky",
                    selection: $selectedItem
                ) {
                    Text("")
                }.hidden()
            }
            HomeView(selectedItem: $selectedItem)
        }
```

In that case make sure your button also selects the sneaky destination link

```
Button("Hello") {
  selectedItem = "Sneaky"
}
```